# Select min of a row value from a set of minimum values of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3w6o.png)

```
SET @jandate1 = '2019-01-31'
SELECT 
min(DATEDIFF (day,@jandate1,review_date)) as rentcount,
min(DATEDIFF(day,@jandate1,expiry_date)) as expcount,
min(DATEDIFF(day,@jandate1,start_date)) as startcount,
min(DATEDIFF(day,@jandate1,termination_date)) as termicount,
min(DATEDIFF(day,@jandate1,first_o_date) as fcount,
min(DATEDIFF(day,@jandate1,Second_o_date) as scount
from datetablex
```

I will get a value for the above query as following

```
rentcount   expcount    startcount termicount  fcount scount
 335           273      -5662        242         273     515
```

Now I need to pick one of expcount or fcount (doest matter for now , ranking coming later) 
and assign a static text to a column like 'expiry' or 'firstoption'
i.e. get the minimum of each row(datediff columns) and based on that set respective static text for that row

Tried unpivot and CASE but going crazy

Comment: What results do you want?  Based on the syntax, I added the SQL Server tag.  Fix the tag if this is not accurate.

Comment: "going crazy" is not a problem description. What output did you attempts give? Why is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `cross apply` to unpivot the data and chose the smallest non-negative value:

```
with t as (
      SELECT min(DATEDIFF(day, @jandate1, review_date)) as rentcount,
             min(DATEDIFF(day, @jandate1, expiry_date)) as expcount,
             min(DATEDIFF(day, @jandate1, start_date)) as startcount,
             min(DATEDIFF(day, @jandate1, termination_date)) as termicount,
             min(DATEDIFF(day, @jandate1, first_o_date) as fcount,
             min(DATEDIFF(day, @jandate1, Second_o_date) as scount
      from datetablex
     )
select t.*, tt.*
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) v.*
      from (values ('rentcount', rentcount),
                   ('expcount', expcount),
                   ('startcount', startcount),
                   ('termicount', termicount),
                   ('fcount', fcount),
                   ('scount', scount)
           ) v(which, cnt)
       where cnt >= 0
       order by cnt asc
      ) tt;
```

Comment: Thank you , it worked for me , I will use this and  put this in subquery to get the 'which' column from the output